# Appending Char array to Char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, copy, char

I have been on this fow quite some time now and i dont seem to figure it out.

I have this code:

```
    unsigned char *src;
    int length = (parameterArray[i].sizeInBits/8) + 1; // check how long array should be
    unsigned char tmp[length]; // declare array

    memcpy(tmp, (char*)&parameterArray[i].valueU8, length); // in this case copy char to array
    src = realloc(src, strlen(src) + strlen(tmp)); // reallocate space for total string
    strncat(src, tmp, strlen(tmp)); // merge
```

every time the code crashes on the reallocating part.

I have tried almost everything and nothing works. Please help

Comment: You don't say what your problem is but note that you should add 1 for a null terminator to the size you `realloc`.  You'd also have problems if `parameterArray[i].valueU8` isn't guaranteed to be null terminated.

Comment: What does not work? How is `parameterArray` defined?

Comment: sorry i edited my question

Comment: Show definition and any use of `src` prior to the call to `realloc()`.

Comment: i only declared it, unsigned char *src;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`src` is an unitialized pointer, and will hold a random memory address. The preconditions for [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) state. from the linked reference page:

> Reallocates the given area of memory. **It must be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc() and not yet freed with free(), otherwise, the results are undefined.**

When using `realloc()` store the result to a temporary variable to avoid a memory leak in the event of failure.

Additionally, calling `strlen()` on `src` will also result in undefined behaviour. As first pointed out by [mani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2223390/mani) `tmp` must be null terminated in order for `strlen()` and `strcpy()` to work correctly. The space calculated in the `realloc()` must be increased by one to allocate an additional `char` for the terminating null character.

Example code fix:

```
unsigned char tmp[length + 1];
memcpy(tmp, parameterArray[i].valueU8, length);
tmp[length] = 0;

unsigned char* src = NULL;
unsigned char* src_tmp = realloc(src, (src ? strlen(src) : 0) + strlen(tmp) + 1);
if (src_tmp)
{
    if (!src) *src_tmp = 0; /* Ensure null character present before strcat(). */
    src = src_tmp;
    strcat(src, tmp);
}
```

Comment: +1, Though the argument to `realloc()` may also be NULL, in which case `realloc()` acts like `malloc()`.

Comment: Ok i know what you mean. If i want to use the chars for other purposes than printing it on the screen would i still be obligated to add a terminating null character?

Comment: @flexzican, almost all c string functions depend upon null terminatination.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code of this line `memcpy(tmp, (char*)&parameterArray[i].valueU8, length);` you are trying to copy `valueU8` which must be assigned with Null terminator. Otherwise it will crash in this line `src = realloc(src, strlen(src) + strlen(tmp));`

Answer (score 0):

From man pages of realloc

> Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to  malloc(), calloc()  or realloc().

and your src is an uninitialized pointer